# How to set drools return message to a variable in mule esb?

Tags: mule, drools, esb

this is my rules.drl :

```
global org.mule.module.bpm.MessageService mule;
import com.hamgam.hit.esb.*; 
import org.mule.MessageExchangePattern

rule "La Vita Ebela"
dialect "mvel"

when
    $x:XMLDTO( inputXML == "inputXML" )
then
    mule.generateMessage("emc",  "emc", null, MessageExchangePattern.ONE_WAY);
end
```

currently it is adding the message to a Queue named "emc", but i need to set it into a variable like :

```
<set-variable variableName="emc" value=""/>
```

i dont know how to set a variable as an endpoint. can any one give me hint?

Answer (score 1):

You only can send a message as far as I know, however what you can do to not to loose original information present in the requesting message is to leverage an [enritcher](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher). A message processor implmeneting the namesake pattern.

Comment: thanks for reply. i changed my strategy, now i am using modify( $x ) { setDestination("EMC") } to set desired value inside the object